# ¿Es mejor .format() o usar una función?

Tags: python

Pregunto si es mejor usar una función o usar el formateo, como por ejemplo con estos dos códigos:

```py
x = 75.4526
y = 12.9717

# Función
sum_two_decimals(x, y):
  return round(x+y, 2)
# Formateo
sum_two_decimals(x, y):
  return float(f"{x+y:.2f}")
```

**La principal razón de mi pregunta es este el siguiente código, en el que tiene mas sentido usar esto ya que se convierte en string de las dos maneras para poder ordenar los números**

Para otra representación fue este código sobre un problema de la constante de Kaprekar, en la que te dan el número de casos, y los números, devolviendo el número de veces que hay que restarlos, etc.

En el uso el formateo %:04, pero no sé si sería mejor usar .zfill(4).
Lo que busco es mejor eficiencia, mejor reabilidad, etc.

```py
n_inputs = int(input())
iterations = []
for i in range(n_inputs):
  num = int(input())
  if num == 6174:
    iterations.append(0)
  elif len(set(f"{num:04}")) == 1:
    iterations.append(8)
  else:
    n_iterations = 0
    while num != 6174:
      num = list(f"{num:04}")
      desc_num = "".join(sorted(num))
      asc_num = "".join(sorted(num, reverse=True))
      num = int(asc_num) - int(desc_num)
      n_iterations += 1
    iterations.append(n_iterations)
iterations = map(str, iterations)    
print("\n".join(iterations))
```

**Aclaro que uso f"{}" en vez de "".format() ya que creo que es mejor para este tipo de código, corregirme si me equivoco, pero al final sigue siendo una abreviación de esta misma.**

Comment: Claramente la primera opción es mejor, ya que solo redondea los números y los suma. Mejor aún si ocurriese la suma primero (`round(x + y, 2)`) ya que solo se llamaría a la función una vez. En cambio, la otra forma tiene que convertir cada número en string para convertirlos en enteros. La conversión es más lenta que simplemente sumarlos. Por otra parte, la conversión es innecesaria ya que `int(str(n))` da el mismo resultado que simplemente `int(n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que para hablar de si son mejor las *f-strings* o el método `.format()` hay que tener en cuenta más aspectos que el de redimiento.

La principal consideración entre usar *f-strings* o `.format()` es el de la seguridad. Las *f-strings* son más fáciles de usar y más legibles, pero más inseguras. Si no tienes control sobre lo que le pasas, pueden suponer un gran agujero de seguridad ya que *"evalúan"* la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```py
x = 1
v = input("Dame un valor:")
print(f"Me has dado el valor {v}")
```

Si introduces `(x:=0)` en el input podrías cambiar la variable `x`, algo que con el método format no pasa.

Por otro lado, nunca son aconsejables las *"optimizaciones tempranas"* con python. En tu código para la *Operación de Kaprekar* tendrías menos problemas para trabajar el número en su representación como string, minimizando las conversiones.

Las conversiones de números a string que incluyen formateo suelen ser bastante costosas, con problemas en los redondeos y con problemas cuando se tratan números de muchas cifras. Pero en tu caso, con números de sólo 4 cifras, no deberías notar mucha diferencia. Pero mi consejo es que evites formateos. Mejor hacer `str(num).zfill(4)` que `f"{num:04}"`.

También hay un detalle que se te ha pasado y es que si ya tienes en número ordenado ascendentemente, basta con hacer un *reverse* en vez de volver a ordenarlo descendentemente: `des_num = asc_num[::-1]`.

```py
n_inputs = int(input())
iterations = []

for i in range(n_inputs):

  num = input()
  assert num.isdigit()
  num = num.zfill(4)

  if len(set(num)) == 1:
    # solución trivial Kaprekar
    iterations.append(0)
  else:
    n_iterations = 0
    while num != "6174":
      asc_num = "".join(sorted(num))
      desc_num = asc_num[::-1]
      num = str(int(desc_num) - int(asc_num)).zfill(4)
      n_iterations += 1
    iterations.append(n_iterations)

for i in iterations:
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es "**depende** del caso concreto". Lo primero  que te debes plantear es que tipo de dato quieres o necesitas. Con esto claro, por lo general cuantas menos llamadas a funciones, conversión de tipos, creación de objetos intermedios, etc (que no sean estrictamente necesarios) apliques mejor.

En tu primer ejemplo necesitas un `float`:

### `round(x + y, 2)`

- Solo hay una llamada a la función `round` que retornara directamente un `float` tras realizar el redondeo.
- Menos código y mas legible, aunque esto pueda ser subjetivo.
- Mas eficiente en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución (y memoria, dado que se evita crear un objeto `str` intermedio):

  ```
  %%timeit
  round(x + y, 2)

  446 ns ± 10.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
  ```

### `float(f"{x + y:.2f}")`

- Aquí primero se convierte el `float` resultante de la suma en una cadena (aplicando el redondeo) y posteriormente se convierte de nuevo la cadena en `float`. Esa conversión a `str` intermedia es contraproducente e innecesaria.
- Es menos legible, cualquiera puede intuir que hace `round()`, la sintaxis `:.2f`  no es tan intuitiva.
- Es menos eficiente:

  ```
  %%timeit
  float(f"{x + y:.2f}")

  560 ns ± 6.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
  ```

Seria distinto si quisieras que la salida fuera una cadena, porque entonces se invierte la situación:

```
%%timeit
str(round(x + y, 2))

1.35 µs ± 250 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
f"{x + y:.2f}"

420 ns ± 9.67 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

En el caso de tu segundo código, tanto `str().zfill()` como f-strings generan una cadena como resultado, aunque si buscas eficiencia parece que `str.zfill` es mejor opción:

```
%%timeit
f"{num:04}"

443 ns ± 8.67 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
str(13).zfill(4)

207 ns ± 10.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Esta diferencia es explicada principalmente porque el método `zfill` esta pensado e implementado precisamente para ser aplicado eficientemente sobre números rellenado con ceros a la izquierda. El formateo de cadenas es mas versátil y genérico que `zfill` pero esa versatilidad tiene su coste.

---

**Nota:** tiempos de ejecución medidos usando el
[comando "mágico" %timeit de IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).